# Removing box shadow just under transparent part of logo

Tags: html, css

I need to remove box-shadow just under the transparent png. Now you can see box shadow under that transparent half circle. Can I do it somehow?

Here is demo.

Problematic part is under the logo.

```css
header {
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    z-index: 10 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
      position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
  left:0px
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<header>
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/sm/20180518/sm_5aff6089d3e02.png" style="height:80px;margin-left:200px">
  <img src="http://vitezslavlorenc.cz/obloucek2.png" style="width: 51px;
    height: 8px;
    /* position: relative; */
    bottom: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 215px;">
</header>
<div style="height:1000px;  width: 1000px;
  ;
  position:relative;">
  <img src="https://wpshindig.com/content/uploads/2018/02/Feature-Header-Image.png" style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:1000px;z-index:-1" >
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/korwinus/pen/bZJOgM

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  i see the white half circle and it covers up the box shadow, I do not see the shadow under it.  I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for here.  This is what I see in Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/I2kygF6.png

Comment: Yes it covers the box shadow, but that half circle is semi-tranparent png, so you can see some parts of that box shadow behind that (not much but its there). What you see in chrome is exactly the problem.

Comment: I'm still not clear... you have a semi-transparent image and _you want to be able to not see though it at all?_  I don't think it's possible to change a transparent png to be opaque within CSS.  Why not just use a fully opaque image, or just draw the shape with CSS using `border-radius`?

Comment: I want that image or shape in css (doesnt matter) to ignore box shadow but also stay transparent. I need that cos that header will have fixed position and will be scrolling with page as user scolls down. I update my code so its more clear.

Comment: i see what you mean now.  you want a shadow, but you want to "cut out a shape" in the shadow, but you also want the cut-out to be transparent to what is behind the shape & shadow,  I'm not sure that this is possible... or at least it would take a lot of work to achieve this effect.  All I know to do would be to create a bunch of transparent elements with shadows and then position them to be around the semi-circle to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Yeah I think that too. I just wanted to be sure. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this codepen link

https://codepen.io/hoonin/pen/OqYVRr

While you can't "hide" the box-shadow in just that portion you can make the image have a higher z-index value than the element with the box shadow. This means it will appear "above" it. Adding a background-color and some bottom padding to the image creates the illusion that the box-shadow disapears in that area.

Here is the code for the class I made for the image (removed the inline styles to):

```
 .ig-logo {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  z-index:9999;
  height:80px;
  margin-left:200px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question code. So now its more clear. I need that parts (header, logo and half circle) to stay transparent. If I put something under that to hide box shadow than some parts will not be transparent.